# How to crop image into a square

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Hi I'm trying to crop images that users upload onto my site into a square. I have already tried a few solutions posted on this website, namely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222711/image-resize-in-c-sharp-algorith-to-determine-resize-dimensions-height-and-wi and [WebImage Crop To Square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535193/webimage-crop-to-square). However, although these solutions convert the image into a square, they add large areas of transparency on the top and bottom of the image, which is not what I want since these images will be used as profile images.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Lamar my question is how would I crop an image into a square without adding large patches of transparency to the top and bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I have always used in my websites:

```
 public Bitmap MakeSquarePhoto(Bitmap bmp, int size)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap res = new Bitmap(size, size);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(res);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, size, size);
                int t = 0, l = 0;
                if (bmp.Height > bmp.Width)
                    t = (bmp.Height - bmp.Width) / 2;
                else
                    l = (bmp.Width - bmp.Height) / 2;
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, size, size), new Rectangle(l, t, bmp.Width - l * 2, bmp.Height - t * 2), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                return res;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, changing the "return bmp" to "return res" made it work. Thank you.

Comment: yes actually if you look i have changed it in the code. my real code gets the stream and saves it directly (does not return anything). I changed it a bit to suit your question, and I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

To crop an image without adding large patches of transparency to the top and bottom, you are going to have to cut off part of the sides. Without seeing the code it should be something along the lines of cutting off (width-height)/2 pixels from each side.